# Identifying a cat parasite

Tags: cats, parasites, identification

Yesterday I let a stray cat sleep on a chair on my balcony.
After it got up, I saw it left dozens of blood filled parasites on the chair, but I'm not sure of which kind.

They are tiny (1-2mm diameter), very slow moving, some are black and some red-ish from blood, they pop easily and leave a bloody splatter, it's hard to see their legs, but they have small antennas.

I'm attaching a photo, but it's not great, as they are too small to easily photograph.

[image: parasite]

Can you identify it? Does it transfer to humans? What should I do?

Comment: is it possible for you to update your question and tell where you live,ticks that live in different parts of the world carry different types of disease so it can make an answer to this more spesific.

Comment: Talk to a vet about it.

Answer (score 2):

It is a tick. They do transfer to all animals living on land. They need blood to live and reproduce.

They can make you and your animal ill, they can transfer serious disease and even kill you or your animal.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tick

It is best to remove it as soon as you see one, to limit the possibility of serious infection in you and your animal.

It is possible to buy tick repellent for you and your pet, but they often do not last for more than a few weeks at most.

Sorry for the short answer, but ticks can be really dangerous.

Comment: Are you sure about this? It seems much smaller than the photos I've seen of ticks. And about 50 of them fell off the cat without loosing their heads. My balcony is full of them :(

Comment: It does look like the uncommon soft-shell variety of ticks...

Comment: take a look in the link provided,i have seen a huge number of ticks in my life.